# How do I set the resolution with a Diamond ATI Radeon 9550?

Tags: 10.04, resolution, radeon

I have ATI Radeon 9550 card, with the open drivers.

In the display properties my screen is not detected,shows UNKNOWN,and don't have 1152x864 which is best for me.

How can i enable it?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to install the AMD Catalyst™ 11.11 Proprietary Linux x86 Display Driver proprietary drivers. Latest release is rather stable. You can get them at [AMD's site](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx). It should allow you to set the resolution you want.